Big Query skip json parsing errors into an error table while continue with rest of the loading process
I am reading json string data from the raw table in Big Query, parse the values and insert them into a processed table. Due to data issues mentioned below, casting operation fails at times.

Invalid Integer or date value
Incorrect date value like 2024-11-31 (like there is no 31st in November)

My requirement is that, i want to continue to insert the good records while writing bad records into an error table.
I have tried with SAFE_CAST options but it gives NULL value,  supress the error and continue. As a result i have to handle expected legit NULL, Empty values before SAFE_CAST is applied to uniquely identify error cases.
Is there a way we skip the error records rather than keeping them as NULL and may be write it to another table in Big Query while loading them into the processed table?
